# PHP working with encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a starting string `$json = {"unit":"\u20ac"}`

Deconding `json_decode($json)` should give `array('unit' => '€')`

But because my web page use `iso-8859-1` as the default encoding, what actually displayed looks like
`array('unit' => 'â‚¬')`

I tried `utf8_encode($arr['unit'])` or `utf8_decode($arr['unit'])`, none of them works. They give respectively `Ã¢Â‚Â¬` and `?`

Everything is broken if use the charset `iso-8859-1`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search provided me with this [link](http://www.pabloviquez.com/2009/07/json-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8-%E2%80%93-part2/) which shows that you need to encode your data before your `json_encode` and also when you use `json_decode` you need to decode it.

`base64_encode(04.utf8_encode('iso-8859-1'));`

the `json_encode` function only works with utf8 encoded data.

Another approach if possible is to change the encoding of your php file? But i assume you wouldn't be asking this question if that was an option.

Comment: Yes, of course I encoded it with json_encode. That's why the `\u20ac` character. I still dont get why you use base64_encode, and how you decode it. I can't change my page encoding, it will mess all up

Comment: Ok after your decode try using `json_last_error()` and see if you get any errors. If you get something like 'JSON_ERROR_UTF8 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

Then you need to use `json_decode($json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Let me know what your error is and we'll see what fix we can find.

Comment: It's not about error when decoding. The symbold display perfectly if use UTF8 charset. But I heard that there is no € equivalent in ISO charset. So I try to find a way...